# Delete empty directories using 'ls' command

Tags: find, ls, pipe, rm

I want to delete empty directories without using `find` command `find . -empty -type d -delete`. like the following:

```
if [ "$(ls -d *)" ]; then
   echo "Not Empty"
else
   echo "Delete"
fi
```

How do I delete empty directories only using `ls`?

Comment: (assuming bash) If you want to traverse an entire directory without `find` and do something with those files, you should either use `globstar` (bash 4+) or recursion. And since I don't think you can make globstar run in DFS order, you would pretty much be limited to recursion.

Comment: Why it has to be without find?

Comment: Here are several methods that you could use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154166/how-to-recursively-list-subdirectories-in-bash-without-using-find-or-ls-commands. You'd need to modify the body of these loops to do the actual deletions.

Answer (score 5):

`rmdir` will delete empty folders (while leaving other folders alone), so you can use something like:

```
rmdir */
```

Or, if you're using bash 4+ and you want recursiveness (other shells have other names for the same thing):

```
shopt -s globstar
rmdir **/
```

This will give you a lot of error messages, however (one for every non-empty folder).

Comment: Thanks! Then how would I list the empty directories with `ls`?

Comment: And how would I delete recursively>

Comment: +1, but still a couple of problems with `globstar`. It doesn't traverse dfs, so if you `/foo/foo1/foo2`, and none of the dirs contain anything else, it will delete `foo2,` but fail for the others. `rmdir **/` is also rather likely to hit `ARG_MAX` and fail for a tree of reasonable size. Also may want to turn `dotglob` on if you want hidden directories.